# do_POST sends 200 response instead of 303

Tags: python, http, post, get, response

I'm new to web servers and I try to build a simple one using `http.server` module from python. I'm working on a local server which displays a form and by submitting this form it should redirect to display the message, so I used `send_response(303)`, but instead of redirecting to homepage, It sends a 200 response.

```py
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

memory = []

form = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
  <title>Message Board</title>
  <form method="POST">
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Post it!</button>
  </form>
  <pre>
{}
  </pre>
'''


class MessageHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        # How long was the message?
        length = int(self.headers.get('Content-length', 0))

        # Read the correct amount of data from the request.
        data = self.rfile.read(length).decode()
        # Extract the "message" field from the request data.
        message = parse_qs(data)["message"][0]

        # Escape HTML tags in the message so users can't break world+dog.
        message = message.replace("<", "&lt;")

        # Store it in memory.
        memory.append(message)

        # 1. Send a 303 redirect back to the root page.
        self.send_response(303)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
        self.send_header('Location', '/') #This will navigate to the original page
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        # First, send a 200 OK response.
        self.send_response(200)

        # Then send headers.
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
        self.end_headers()

        # 2. Put the response together out of the form and the stored messages.
        response = ""
        for message in memory:
          response += f"{message}\n"

        # 3. Send the response.
        self.wfile.write(form.format(response).encode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, MessageHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: How do you check your response? Most things just follow redirects by default.

Comment: Running this and submitting only displays the message I've submitted in a clear page

Answer (score 0):

I think this is working as you intended it.

Here is the call log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2020 10:42:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2020 10:42:23] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2020 10:42:39] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 303 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2020 10:42:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2020 10:42:39] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

when you do a `POST` it's returning with 303, When the browser receives that it fires another `GET` request to which the server responds with 200